# Notation in analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, notation

Could someone please explain the following notation
$$||f_j||_{\infty}$$

Its used in convergence theorems but I dont understand the double lines or the infinity symbol.

Comment: $||f||_\infty$ is the largest value that the function $f$ takes. Or, the smallest value larger than any value $f$ takes, in the case where the maximum value is never exactly achieved (e.g., there is a sequence of points $x$ with $f(x)=0.9$, $0.99$, $0.999$, etc, but never exactly $1$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  double bar notation $\| \cdot\|$ is sometimes used to denote [some kinds of norms in mathematics](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleBar.html). The question was already dealt with in [What does double vertical-line means in linear algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586245/what-does-double-vertical-line-means-in-linear-algebra) A standard class of norms are the $\ell_p$ norms, with $1\le p < \infty$, in finite (or countably infinite) dimension spaces: 
$$ \| f\|_p = \left(\sum_i|f_i|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\,.$$
When $p\to \infty$, $\| f\|_p \to \| f\|_\infty = \sup_i |f_i| $.

Otherwise, $\left(\int|f(t)|^p  dt\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ denotes the  $L_p$ norm, and for $p = \infty$, it characterizes  essentially bounded functions, i.e. bounded up to a set of measure zero, as given in @Bungo comment.

The $_\infty$ notation is thus consistent with classical norms.

On the [historical side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols_by_introduction_date): John Wallis is credited  with introducing the "[lemniscatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate)" (from latin, and greek, decorated with ribbons) for the  infinity symbol with its mathematical meaning in 1655. The double-bar notation was introduced to denote matrices by Cayley (1843), but was apparently used by Erhard Schmidt in 1907 to introduce a norm notation.

Answer (score 3):

This could be the [sup norm (uniform norm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm):
$$
\|f\|_\infty = \sup_x |f(x)|
$$

Comment: Or perhaps the $L^{\infty}$ norm, which ignores "outliers" on a set of measure zero: $\|f\|_{\infty} = \inf\{c \geq 0 \mid |f(x)| \leq c \text{ almost everywhere}\}$