# How to understand equation $\parallel x - x^\prime||^2_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, notation

For this equation  :

$$\parallel x - x^\prime||^2_2$$

From [What does double vertical-line means in linear algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586245/what-does-double-vertical-line-means-in-linear-algebra/586375) I understand what $\parallel$ signify.

What does 2 represent in this problem? The upper 2 represents an exponent? What does 2 at lower position represent?

Comment: The upper 2 is an exponent.  $||\cdot||_2$ is the Euclidean norm, so altogether it just means  $\sum_i{(x_i-x'_i)^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $2$ at the upper position is just an exponent. The $2$ at the lower position represents the Euclidean norm (frequently called $2$-norm). It is defined as $$\Vert x \Vert_2 = \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n \vert x_i \vert^2\right)^{1/2} \qquad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb R^n.$$ One can generalize this construction for $1 \leq p < \infty$ to get the $p$-norm defined by 
$$\Vert x \Vert_p = \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n \vert x_i \vert^p\right)^{1/p} \qquad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb R^n.$$ 
Due to this generalization one calls the Euclidean norm frequently the $2$-norm. I hope things got clearer for you :)